# What is the name/number of this Technic brick with two arms ending in tiny clips?

Tags: technic, part-identification

What is the number of the brick shown below? I have been searching, but had no success. There is no number shown on the brick, but it has the LEGO logo.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

That's two [Magnet Holder 2 x 3](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?id=171#T=C), it has part number 2607.